# Simplify method in an Enum class in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have a class that contains an Enum to do calculation.
Each Enum uses some or all of the non-static variables from the outer class. However since they can't access instance variable, I have to pass in them as parameters.

```
public class Outer{
    ClassA a;
    ClassB b;
    ClassC c;
    Map<MyEnum,Double> results= new EnumMap(MyEnum.class);
    private enum MyEnum{
        X{  public double calc(ClassA _a){ dostuff }           },
        Y{  public double calc(ClassB _b,ClassC _c){ dostuff } },
        Z{  public double calc(ClassA _a,ClassB _b){ dostuff } };
    }

    public void doCalc(){
        for(MyEnum item:MyEnum.values()){
            result.get(item) = item.calc(...);//Not uniform here
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I can't have a uniform way to pass in the parameters in the for-loop. I could make each Enum method takes all classes like

```
public double calc(ClassA _a,ClassB _b,ClassC _c){ dostuff}
```

But if I have more classes, the parameter will look too ugly. Is there a better way to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why don't you pass the instance of outer to the `calc()` method. In that case, each specific enum will have the logic to deal with the `Outer` object accordingly and new enums wouldn't require any change.

```
class Outer {

    ClassA a;
    ClassB b;
    ClassC c;
    Map<MyEnum,Double> results= new EnumMap<MyEnum, Double>(MyEnum.class);
    private enum MyEnum{
        X{  public void calc(Outer o){ }           },
        Y{  public void calc(Outer o){  } },
        Z{  public void calc(Outer o){ } };
        abstract void calc(Outer o);
    }

    public void doCalc(){
        for(MyEnum item:MyEnum.values()){
            item.calc(this);
        }
    }
}


class ClassA {}
class ClassB {}
class ClassC {}
```

Comment: Amazing how similar our code samples look! Even though I question the OP's design I give +1 for sheer correctedness :). And for beating me to the punch :(

Comment: @Perception: +1 for questioning the OP's design, just what I was thinking. I'd be interested in actually knowing what was intended here. Oh, and not to forget, great minds think alike. ;-)

Comment: Totally missed this possibility when considering my answer, but of course this would be better.  Although still wondering about some of the design, as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could change your enum method to:

```
public double calc(Object... params) {
    switch(this) {
        case X:
            // cast params needed for X methodology.
            // doXStuff
            break;
        case y:
            . . . 
    }
}
```

Comment: it is kind of an ugly way to do it but works fine I guess +1.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that you have different method implementation on the ENUM values
On Java 8 you can use BiFunction:

```
    public static class Outer {

    Map<MyEnum, Double> results = new EnumMap(MyEnum.class);

    public enum MyEnum {
        X(defaultdoStuff1()),
        Y(defaultdoStuff1()),
        Z(defaultdoStuff2());

        MyEnum(BiFunction<Object, Integer, Boolean> objectIntegerBooleanBiFunction) {
            this.handler = objectIntegerBooleanBiFunction;
        }

        private BiFunction<Object, Integer, Boolean> handler;

        private static BiFunction<Object, Integer, Boolean> defaultdoStuff2() {
            //do stuff
            return (obj, age) -> (age > 0) || obj != null;
        }

        private static BiFunction<Object, Integer, Boolean> defaultdoStuff1() {
            //do stuff
            return (obj, age) -> false;
        }
    }

}
```