# Enums: methods exclusive to each one of the instances

Tags: java, compiler-construction, syntax, enums

From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6551597/812139) I have learnt that it is possible in Java to **define specific methods for each one of the instances of an Enum**:

```
public class AClass {

    private enum MyEnum{
        A { public String method1(){ return null; } },
        B { public Object method2(String s){ return null; } },
        C { public void method3(){ return null; } } ;
    }

    ...
}
```

I was surprised that this is even possible, do this "exclusive methods" specific to each instance have a *name* to look for documentation?

Also, **how is it supposed to be used**? Because the next is not compiling:

```
    private void myMethod () {
        MyEnum.A.method1();
    }
```

How am I supposed to use these "exclusive" methods?

Comment: MyEnum.A.method1();
does not compile, because all the compiler knows is that MyEnum.A is of type MyEnum, and you have not declared any methods for this enum.

The "name" you are looking for are anyonymuous classes in enum definitions.

Comment: @Peter: Sorry, I posted the comment before I completed it.

Comment: @Andreas: I've removed my obsolete comment already :)

Comment: Note that while this isn't currently possible it is on the table for a future Java version as [JEP 301: Enhanced Enums](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/301).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot refer to those methods, because you are effectively creating anonymous (*) class for each enum. As it is anonymous, you can reference such methods only from inside your anonymous class itself or through reflection.

This technique is mostly useful when you declare abstract method in your enumeration, and implement that method for each enum individually.

(*) JLS 8.9 Enums part says: "The optional class body of an enum constant implicitly defines an anonymous class declaration (§15.9.5) that extends the immediately enclosing enum type."

Comment: Thanks! and then, why is this allowed in Java? have you got any reference to this particularity?

Comment: @edutesoy: JLS 8.9 Enums part says: "The optional class body of an enum constant implicitly defines an anonymous class declaration (§15.9.5) that extends the immediately enclosing enum type." But I was wrong about referencing it ... you can of course reference such methods from inside your anonymous class itself. It should also be possible to reference it through reflection, and if you guess the name of anonymous class (it's not so anonymous in the end), maybe also through ((Enum$0) A).method() ... not that I would use that (I'm not even sure if it works).

Comment: I suggest you to add this last comment to your answer. I will accept it. Thank you!!

Comment: @edutesoy: ok, did so. I've edited my answer slightly to still make sense.

Answer (score 22):

You need to declare abstract methods in your enum which are then implemented in specific enum instances.

```
class Outer {

    private enum MyEnum {
        X {
            public void calc(Outer o) {
                // do something
            }
        },
        Y {
            public void calc(Outer o) {
                // do something different
                // this code not necessarily the same as X above
            }
        },
        Z {
            public void calc(Outer o) {
                // do something again different
                // this code not necessarily the same as X or Y above
            }
        };

        // abstract method
        abstract void calc(Outer o);
    }

    public void doCalc() {
        for (MyEnum item : MyEnum.values()) {
            item.calc(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's if he wants all instances to share a method but have separate implementations, and from what I've gathered, I don't think this is the case.

Comment: True, i want "specific methods" for each instance, because java seems to allow it... From my point of view, this answer does not answer any of the two questions I made.

Comment: @Sanjay: finally an answer that makes sense!

Comment: @edutesoy: If you want method implementation specific to each enum (i.e. `doCalc` different for each enum) use the approach which I have provided. Otherwise, you can have normal methods on enums (which are not put in specific enum instances) which can be accessible for all enum instances.

Comment: @Sanjay, i downvoted it because it doesn't meet my answer, please, could you modify your answer to meet the questions i did? specially, how can i access the MyEnum.A.method1(); (or some explanation about its impossibility) without modifying the Enum (which seems to be legal in Java language). Just trying tu understand better the enums, not facing any practical problem. I would be glad to accept it.

Comment: @edutesoy: your question doesn't make sense. The enum instances must share the same method signatures. They may change behavior by using different method bodies, but their signatures must match. If you know of a link that shows otherwise, please by all means share it.

Comment: The structure is valid in Java, I am asking how is it supposed to be used.

Comment: @Sanjay: I can only guess that the down voter is showing their ignorance somehow.

Comment: @edutesoy: then please demonstrate this by posting compilable Java code that shows that it's valid. Your question's code certainly isn't compilable.

Comment: @ Sanjay, I didn't down-vote...I did remove my incorrect answer though.

Comment: The first code snippet is compilable. It is allowed in Java, but it seems to be impossible to use it (the second snippet is an example of this)...

Comment: @edutesoy: but the correct answer in the link you've provided -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551597/simplify-method-in-an-enum-class-in-java -- is the same as Sanjay's answer above. That **is** the solution -- to use an abstract method with a single signature that is overridden in the enum instances.

Answer (score 6):

Each `enum` is an anonymous inner class. So like any anonymous inner class, you can add all of the methods you want, but there is no way to reference them outside of the class, as the class doesn't have a type that defines the methods.

The advantage of allowing methods on the `enum` implementation is that it allows for a strategy pattern, where the enum itself has an abstract method or a default implementation, and specific members of the `enum` have implementations of that method that may do something different.

I have used this technique to greatly reduce code complexity on switch statements. Instead of switching on the enum in some other class, just get a reference to it and call a method, and let the enum itself take care of it. Of course that depends on the scenario if it makes sense, but it can reduce code complexity tremendously.

Comment: *So like any anonymous inner class... there is no way to reference them outside of the class*. The fact that it's anonymous is a technicality; you can still access the method through its implicit type: `new Object() { public void foo() {} }.foo();`. I see no reason why enum constants couldn't work the same way when referenced directly.