# Switch console menu to enum

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I've a menu like this:

```
 switch(menumain.getOpcao()){
            case 1:
                signIn();
                break;
            case 2:
                signUp();
                break;
        }
    }while (menumain.getOpcao()!=0);
```

I want to remove switch statements and make the menu with Enum. Is that possible?
Currently I've something like this:

```
public enum menuInicial {

  SIGNIN(1) {
      TraderApp.signIn();
  },
  SIGNUP(2) {
    public void doSomething() {

    }
  },
  UNKNOWN(3) {
    public void doSomething() {

    }
  };
  private int value;
  public abstract void doSomething();
  private menuInicial(int value) {
      this.value = value;
   }
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enums: methods exclusive to each one of the instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551851/enums-methods-exclusive-to-each-one-of-the-instances)

Comment: My signIn() and signUp methods are not in the Enum class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that (although I'm not sure it's a good idea to put a lot of business logic into an `enum`:

```
public enum MenuInicial {
    SIGNIN(1, TraderApp::signIn),
    SIGNUP(2, TraderApp::signUp),
    UNKNOWN(3, () -> doSomething());

    private int value;
    private Runnable execution;

    private MenuInicial(int val, Runnable toRun) {
        int value = val;
        execution = toRun;
    }
    public void execute() { 
        execution.run();
    }

    static void execute(int code) {
        for (MenuInicial item : values()) {
            if (item.value == code) {
                item.run(); break;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown code " + code);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm getting the errors: 
- Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method signIn() from the type 

- The constructor MenuInicial(int, TraderApp::signIn) is undefined

Comment: @RogérioMoreira Well yes, all methods referred to need to be `static` for this to work.

Comment: @RogérioMoreira You could add a `setter` method for the `Runnable`s and initialize them later, but that would be a bit dangerous depending on when what code is called.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a *state machine*; somewhat like:

```
enum State {
    A(ctxt -> B),
    B(ctxt -> C),
    C(ctxt -> A);

    protected final Function<CTXT, State> transition;

    State(Function<CTXT, State> transition) {
        this.transition = transition;
    }

    public State takeStep(CTXT context) {
        // context.setState(this);
        return transition.apply(context);
    }
}
```

As an enum can be mapped (see EnumMap and EnumSet), this can be achieved by a small enum without logic too, and then a map to transitions. The *strategy pattern*.

But when one adds function references:

```
enum State {
    A(f::initialize),
    B(g::work),
    C(f::goodnight); ...
}
```

It might become compact.

Comment: Hi @Joop thank you so much for your answer. I don't quite get it, can you explain better? Thank you so much for helping.